# Tensorflow slowing down in a loop

Tags: python, performance, loops, tensorflow

I have multiple algorithms I run in loops. Those that contain tensorflow really slow down after multiple iterations.

Each file list will be roughly 10,000 files depending on which algorithm it is. I loop through the file list one file at a time, creating a data frame from each file, running my algorithm on the data frame then writing the result to a database. Looks something like:

```
file_list = self.get_files()
for file in file_list:
   data = self.get_data(file.fileid)
   result = self.get_result(data)
   self.write_result
```

`get_result` is a different function for different algorithms. They normally take 0 - 5 seconds to calculate the results per file.

I'm working with an algorithm at the minute that at the beginning of the loop processes 2 files per second, but after a few hundred files it slows down to a minute per file. Inspecting the code it has to be TF that is the bottleneck as the rest of the code is relatively trivial.

In `get_result` there is the following line that I believe is the culprit:

`z = self.evaluate_risk(normalized_X)`

```
def evaluate_risk(self, X):    

    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, model.pb)
            graph = tf.get_default_graph()
            input_x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
            risk = graph.get_tensor_by_name("risk:0")
            z = sess.run(risk, {input_x: X})
            sess.close()
            del sess
            del graph
    return z
```

Given that I'm using `with` I don't understand why this function is causing any issues. I have since added `sess.close()`, `del sess` and `del graph` but I still get the same issue.

Each time I have a new file and get to `result` I should be starting tensorflow from fresh. Are there any obvious reasons my loop slows down? I'm guessing some part of tensorflow isn't resetting.

Comment: The main problem is with `tf.saved_model.loader.load`, it is loading the model multiple times and cramming the graph with copies. You could fix replacing `with tf.Session() as sess:` with `with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:`, but ideally you should load the model once, out of that function. To make things slightly faster, you could do the `get_tensor_by_name` calls also only once (save the returned value in an instance variable like `self.input_x`, for example). The second source of delay is the creation of the session, it's much faster to create a single session and reuse it.

Comment: Loading things once wouldn't work here. My file_list increases with time, after the 10k is run I expect ~10 files added per day. The model was developed on historical data and now is used on new incoming data. 

Why doesn't the `del graph` line deal with cramming the graph with copies?

Comment: KeyError: "The name 'input:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'input', does not exist in the graph."

Comment: I _think_ that the changes to `file_list` do not affect here, you will just be passing a different `X` in `{input_x: X}` to the same graph. `del graph` doesn't do anything, you are using the default graph and that only deletes that reference, but it is still referenced internally by TensorFlow (thus not freed).

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing a complete example it is hard to tell what is the best solution, but generally I would load the model only once (maybe in a graph of its own) and create only one session, then use that in `evaluate_risk`. That should reduce significantly the overhead of each call. You could do something like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    # ... init code
    self.graph = tf.Graph()  # Have the model live in its own graph
    with self.graph.as_default(), tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        self.session = tf.Session()
        tf.saved_model.loader.load(self.session, model_pb)
        self.input_x = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
        self.risk = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("risk:0")

def __del__(self):
    # Ensure the session is closed when the object is deleted
    # (or do it in another method, or make the object work as a context manager, ...)
    self.session.close()

def evaluate_risk(self, X):
    return self.session.run(self.risk, {self.input_x: X})
```

EDIT: Closing the session in the `__del__` method may be superfluous, as in principle when the object is deleted its session will be too, and thus closed. However, it avoids the potential issue of someone grabbing a reference to the session in the object (like `obj_session = my_object.session`), which could result in the session not being closed as expected. It also makes clearer when the session is expected to be closed.

Comment: I will see if this works. `evaluate_risk` is only called once for each `get_results` (so per file). I have roughly 100 algorithms running this way, but perhaps I should write a different structure for the few that use tensorflow and create the session/graph before looping through the file list?

Comment: @Olivia Well I don't know how this may or may not fit within your larger picture. As I said, if, in your original code, you simply replace `with tf.Session() as sess:` with `with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:`, at least it should stop it from becoming slower and slower (it will make a new graph on each call and then discard it, so there will be an overhead from making the session and loading the model, but it should always be the same). You may decide what is really the best solution in your context.

Comment: When I try the solution in the first comment: `tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:,` it fails, then when I swap it round: `tf.Session() as sess,tf.Graph().as_default():,`  I get KeyError: "The name 'input:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'input', does not exist in the graph."

Comment: @Olivia Yea turning it around wouldn't work, because then `sess` is created in the default graph but then a different graph is set as default, so it would load the model in the graph of `sess` but `tf.get_default_graph()` would return a different (and empty) one. What is the error with `with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:`?

Comment: It's working now. I used that then commented out `graph =` line in my original code. Not sure why it was failing before, Ill blame pycharm lol. Lets see if this is faster. I wasnt able to implement your method. In my py file I have `__all__ = ['algorithm1']` at the top then a function used for data transformation. Then a class called `dataloader` with a few functions that transform the data so it works with tensorflow. Then a `algorithm1` class that within it has `evaluate_risk` then `get_results`. If I put your 3 functions under `__all__` it tells me init has 2 positional arguments.

Comment: If I put it in the algorihtm1 class it can't seem to find session. Note that `__all__` is only used so another file that calls different algorithms doesn't have to use the path for every algorithm.

Comment: @Olivia Glad you got at least one alternative working. Not sure about the other thing, in principle those functions would go within `algorithm1` I think, the code in `__init__` and `__del__` would extend whatever `__init__` and `__del__` (if you have that) methods already there. I fixed an error in my `evaluate_risk` earlier where I had writter `sess` instead of `self.session`, not sure if that was it...

Comment: Not sure, I'll try again if this doesnt speed things up. I used `self.sess = tf.Session()` in init then `self.sess.close` in del and `self.sess.run(self.risk, {self.input_x: X})` in evaluate_risk so not sure what it didn't like.